# Prove that $\lim_{\lambda \to \pm \infty} \int_{a}^{\infty} f (x) e^{i \lambda x} \, d x = 0$

Tags: limits, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

> Suppose that $\int_{a}^{\infty} f (x) \, d x$ converges absolutely.

This looks like the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma. Can I use a similar proof? However, the assumption in the Lemma is that $f (x)$ is Riemann integrable, whereas in this question we are given absolute convergence.

Edit: Proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma:

Suppose $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. then given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a partition $\{ a = x_{0}, x_{1}, \dots, x_{n} = b \}$, so that $\displaystyle \epsilon / 2 > \int_{a}^{b} f - \sum_{1}^{n} m_{i} \Delta x_{i} \geq 0$, where $m_{i}$ is the minimum of $f$ on $[x_{i-1}, x_{i}]$. But the sum can be written as $\displaystyle \sum_{1}^{n} m_{i} \Delta x_{i} = \int_{a}^{b} g$, where $\displaystyle g = \sum m_{i} \chi_{x_{i - 1, x_{i}}}$, and the inequality takes the form
$$ \epsilon/2 > \int_{a}^{b} (f - g) \geq 0 .$$
Now we use the fact that $f-g \geq 0$ to get
\begin{align*} \left\rvert \int_{a}^{b} f(x) e^{i \lambda x} \, dx \right\rvert &\leq \left\rvert \int_{a}^{b} \left[ f(x) - g(x) \right] e^{i\lambda x} \, dx \right\rvert + \left\rvert \int_{a}^{b} g(x) e^{i\lambda x} \, dx \right\rvert \\
&\leq \int_{a}^{b} (f - g) \, dx + (\lambda/1) \left\rvert \sum m_{i} (e^{i\lambda x_{i}} - e^{\lambda x_{i - 1}}) \right\rvert \end{align*}

The function $g$ has been fixed. Take $\lambda$ large enough that
$$ (\lambda/1) \left\rvert \sum m_{i} (e^{i\lambda x_{i}} - e^{\lambda x_{i - 1}}) \right\rvert < \epsilon / 2 $$

Therefore,
$$ \left\rvert \int_{a}^{b} f(x) e^{i \lambda x} \, dx \right\rvert < \epsilon $$

Comment: Riemann-Lebesgue lemma is explained here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma)

Comment: This follows directly from the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma. What's your definition of $\int_a^{\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ converging absolutely? To me, it means that $\int_a^{\infty}|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x<\infty$, which is to say that $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable and hence the Riemann-Lebesgue-Lemma applies.

Comment: Do you know that characteristic functions of intervals are dense in $L^1(R)$?

Comment: @Matematleta We don't. Our textbook (Advanced Calculus by Folland) has a definition for $L^2$.

Comment: What is your statement of the "usual" Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma and how did you prove it?

Comment: @Matematleta Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma: Suppose $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$, then $\lim_{|s| \to \infty} \int_a^b f(x) e^{isx} \, dx = 0$. We used a proof similar to this https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_Lemma.

Comment: The proof that you referenced in your last comment suffices here.  Note that $\mathscr{L}^1$ convergence is absolute convergence.

Comment: If the limits of integration are finite and $f$ is Riemann integrable you can do it with partitions. Is this the way you did it? If the limits are not finite and $f$ is $L^1$ the only way I know is by using a density argument.

Comment: @Matematleta I added the proof of the RL Lemma.

Comment: OK, so if $f$ is Riemann integrable then repeat your proof on the intervals $[a,n], [n,n+1],[n+1,n+2],\cdots,$ where $n$ is the first integer after $a$ and choose your partition on each $[k,k+1]$ so that the difference in the sums of the integrals on each $[k,k+1]]$ is $<\epsilon/2^k.$ Then, summing to get the improper integral, you will get that $\int_a^{\infty} *<\sum \epsilon/2^k=\epsilon.$

Comment: @Matematleta Would I need to assume that $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: If you assume that $f$ is $L^1$ only, then the same proof goes through as long as you know that the step functions are dense in $L^1$ because your approximation argument is with step functions and you now need to know that the same procedure works for $L^1$ functions.